# How to use diffrent array values each time ajax is called?

Tags: ajax, arrays

I have this function that runs every 5 seconds.Each time the function runs i want to use next value in array till i reach end of the array then stop that function from running. My current code only uses first item of the array each time the function runs! array index never gets incremented somehow!

could any one tell me how i can use different items in array and stop running the function when i reach end of array ?

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">


window.setInterval(function(){

episode=["http://www.asite.com/video1&title=video1 title","http://www.asite.com/video2&title=video2 title"];
m=0;
//alert ("wow");
$.ajax(
{


    type: 'GET',

        url: './getit.php?url='+episode[m],

            success: function (good)
            {
              //handle success

                  //alert(good)
                 $('#myDiv2').append(good)

             $("textarea[name='content']").html($("textarea[name='content']").html()+"\n"+good);
                m++;

            },
            failure: function (bad)
            {
               //handle any errors

                alert(bad)

            }




});

}, 5000);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="myDiv2"></div>
<textarea name="content" rows="30" cols="150" ></textarea>

</html>
```

Comment: looks to me like you're setting `m=0` each time the function runs. You should try instantiating `m` outside of the `setInterval` function.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `m` variable outside the function:

```
m = 0;
window.setInterval(function(){ //do more stuff now
```

Then run a check to verify that `m` is not greater than the array length.

```
if (m < episode.length) {
    //m is still within the array length, do stuff
} else {
    return; //m is too big, bail
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I placed m=0 outside function and still array index doesn't get incremented m++ ! so first array item get send to ajax every 5 seconds!

Comment: Are you sure your success function is being reached and `m` is being incremented?

Comment: thanks now it increment the array index! Is there away to halt the timer when end of array index reached ? how?

Comment: you can use clearInterval -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.clearInterval